# Коллекция из нескольких String, String

Tags: java, строки, коллекции

Как хранить коллекцию из нескольких значений, к примеру, `String, Object`? Есть для этого что-нибудь лучше `ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>`? Если будут 3 аргумента(`String, Object, Object`), как хранить их?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй создать общий интерфейс и нужные тебе реализации от него. Затем создавай уже ArrayList<ТвойИнтерфейс>